# Deselect an item from Feature View?

Tags: installshield, installscript

If you have worked on installscript of InstallShield. You might also came across to this condition when you have a 'Feature View' and all in the list are selected by default. How can we deselect them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the FeatureSetData() and FeatureSelectItem() functions:

**FeatureSetData ( szFeatureSource, szFeature, nInfo, nData, szData );**
The FeatureSetData function sets properties and data for the specified feature. Most of the settings correspond to the properties in the Features view.

**FeatureSelectItem ( szFeatureSource, szFeature, bSelect );**
The FeatureSelectItem function sets a feature's selection status to either selected or not selected. You can use FeatureSelectItem to change selection status before displaying features in feature dialogs, and you can use it to change or override selections afterward, depending on your setup's requirements.